# Function doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used

Tags: vb.net, function, reference, null, return

I'm getting this error:

> Function 'getkey' doesn't return a value on all code paths.
>   A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is
>   used.

to the following code:

```
 Public Function getkey(ByVal id As String)
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Try
                cmd = New SqlCommand("dbo.getkeydesc", GenLog.cn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
                Dim r As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If r.HasRows Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Finally
                ' If Not cn Is Nothing Then cn.Close()
            End Try
        End Function
```

I tried all possible solutions and they didn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Catch` block doesn't return a value.  Change it to where it returns a value, like so:

```
Public Function getkey(ByVal id As String)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Try
            cmd = New SqlCommand("dbo.getkeydesc", GenLog.cn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
            Dim r As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If r.HasRows Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            Return False
        Finally
            ' If Not cn Is Nothing Then cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

No value will be returned if an exception is thrown in that try..catch block. You either need to provide a return value in case an exception is thrown (by returning something in either the catch block, or you need to rethrow the exception.

```
Public Function getkey(ByVal id As String)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Try
            cmd = New SqlCommand("dbo.getkeydesc", GenLog.cn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
            Dim r As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If r.HasRows Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            ' Either do this:
            ' Return False
            ' or this:
            ' Throw ex
        Finally
            ' If Not cn Is Nothing Then cn.Close()
        End Try
    End Function
```