# Function doesn't return a value on all code paths

Tags: database, vb.net, key, oledb

I am working on a program that creates random generated Keys, and for every Key generated a function is used to Insert it into a local created **oleDB**. The problem I have is that somehow does not Insert the keys into the database. At the end of the Insert function its stated that it does not return a value to all code paths, which I don't know how to "fix".

**Below is the InsertData Function :**

```
Public Function InsertData(ByVal sKey As String, ByVal sUsability As String, ByVal sAssNr As String, ByVal sAvailability As String, ByVal sToday As Date, ByVal sUsername As String, ByVal sAvailavble As Byte) As String

        Try
            Dim sqlconn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim sqlquery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            Dim connString As String
            connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & modMain.msv_sMSAccess_File_Path & "\" & modMain.msv_sMSAccess_File_Name & "; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & modCrypto.Decrypt(modMain.msv_sMSAccess_File_Password, modMain.sKey, modMain.sSalt, 256) & ";ole db services=-4;"   ';ole db services = -4 >> kein connection pooling
            sqlconn.ConnectionString = connString
            sqlquery.Connection = sqlconn
            sqlconn.Open()
            sqlquery.CommandText = "Insert Into " & frmMain.ToolStrip_Main_SelectYr.Text & "(Gutscheincode, Verwendungsanzahl, Assistent, Gueltig_bis, Erstellt_am, Erstellt_vom, verbraucht) VALUES ('" & sKey & "','" & sUsability & "','" & sAssNr & "','" & sAvailability & "','" & sToday & "','" & sUsername & "','" & sAvailavble & "');"
            sqlconn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Function
```

**And this is the function to create the Database:**

```
Friend Function createTable(ByVal sTablename As String, ByVal iYear As Integer) As Boolean

        Dim VoucherDB As New OleDbConnection(getProviderString())
        Dim SQLStr As String = "CREATE TABLE " & sTablename & iYear & " (voucher_ID COUNTER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_ID_no PRIMARY KEY, " &
                                                                        "Gutscheincode                                  Varchar(255) ," &
                                                                        "Verwendungsanzahl                              Varchar(255) ," &
                                                                        "Assistent                                      Varchar(255) ," &
                                                                        "Gueltig_bis                                    Varchar(255) ," &
                                                                        "Erstellt_am                                    DateTime DEFAULT Now, " &
                                                                        "Erstellt_vom                                   Varchar(255) ," &
                                                                        "Verbraucht                                     Bit DEFAULT FALSE " &
                                                                        ")"  'wichtig bei der letzten Spalte >> Rechnungsnummer darf hinter dem Datentyp kein Komma mehr stehen

        Dim DBCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQLStr, VoucherDB)

        Try
            VoucherDB.Open() 'Payment Tabelle erzeugen
            DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            VoucherDB.Close()

            VoucherDB.Dispose()
            Return True

        Catch ex As OleDbException
            frmMain.LogMessage(modMain.msv_sAppname_Short & ", Fehler beim erstellen der Leerdatenbank " & modMain.sMSAccess_File_Name & ". Es kam zu folgender Exception : " & ex.Message, 3)
            If VoucherDB IsNot Nothing Then VoucherDB.Close()
            Return False
        End Try


    End Function
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: your `InsertData` function is supposed to return a string, but it doesn't return anything. You need at least one `Return` statement somewhere in that function. Or, if you don't need it to return a value, you can change it into a `Sub` instead of a `Function`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/function-procedurename-doesn-t-return-a-value-on-all-code-paths

Comment: P.S. your code is horribly vulnerable to [SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/), you should fix that a.s.a.p.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721925/function-doesnt-return-a-value-on-all-code-paths-a-null-reference-exception-co)

Comment: Side note: you should be ensuring your commands/connections are closed/disposed of. Are you sure they would be cleaned up if an exception occurs?